# Custom PerfCounter: no data in WADPerformanceCountersTable

Tags: azure, performancecounter, azure-worker-roles

I got custom performance counter in worker role. It works fine, I can see it in RDP.

OnStart method:

```
...
            var dmc = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

            dmc.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(
                new PerformanceCounterConfiguration
                {
                    CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time",
                    SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                });

            dmc.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(
                new PerformanceCounterConfiguration
                {
                    // my counter
                    CounterSpecifier = @"\..ProcessorWorkerCounters\# of active items",
                    SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                });

            dmc.Logs.BufferQuotaInMB = 4;

            // Get the perf counters
            dmc.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            dmc.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
            dmc.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;

            var cloudStorageAccount =
                CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"));

            DiagnosticMonitor.Start(cloudStorageAccount, dmc);


...
```

But there is no data in WADPerformanceCountersTable for my counter. What is the problem?

**UPD**: `"\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"` counter is ok - there is a data in wad-table.

**UPD2**: Some worker role is using this custom counter. If there is only one instance of that role there is no data. But if there are 2 instances - there is data from instance #2.

Comment: Have you tried it with just the first counter to make sure that works?

Comment: tom, it works fot CPU counter. I updated topic.